# Question on Utility Application - iPhone SDK

Tags: iphone, view, utility

I have this application I made on a utility based app. How would I incorporate this app into a view based application so I can run the code from there.. Like 2 seperate projects in one. I basically want to open/show the utility app in my view based application when I press a button.. Is this possible??

Comment: Are you trying to have one application launch another? Or are you trying to take the screens from one app, and make them part of another app?

Comment: Trying to have one application launch another..

Comment: So do want to open viewApp-->hit button --> quit Viewapp --> autolaunch utility app? Or do you want to open viewApp-->hit button --> open utility app as a view inside viewApp?

Comment: I guess the second option. You see my utility app is a game, and I want to open it in my view controller. I don't want a separate app, since that's going to be a pain in the butt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to implement a URL scheme for the app you want to launch.  Then from the calling app have something like this:

```
NSURL *appUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myapp://foo/bar"];
UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
if ([app canOpenURL:appUrl]) {
    [app openURL:appUrl];
} else {
    // tell user they need to have this other app installed.
}
```

More info about how to do this here:
http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html